# How do I make my Jbutton write to a file. I keep getting throws FileNotFound Exception Errors

Tags: java, file, actionlistener

```
    private static class WithdrawButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        WithdrawAmount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the amount you want to withdraw: ", "Withdraw Amount", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        PrintWriter foutWithdraw= new PrintWriter("Transaction History");

        if(Integer.parseInt(WithdrawAmount)<=CurrentBalance){
            CurrentBalance = CurrentBalance - Integer.parseInt(WithdrawAmount);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have successfully withdrawn "+ Integer.parseInt(WithdrawAmount)+ " AED from your account");
            foutWithdraw.print("$"+Integer.parseInt(WithdrawAmount)+" has been withdrawn from account 1111");
        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You cannot withdraw an amount more than the current balance.");
    }
}
```

There's an error on the PrintWriter area, it says I have to have a FileNotFoundException but I don't know how to add that exception to an ActionListener class.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add the exception to the metho but rather deal with it directly by surrounding the part of the code uses the PrintWriter with a try-catch and handle the exception somehow, maybe with an alert.

That being said, I think it's a weird place to write transactions to file.